# C# threading - resetThread is a 'variable' but is used like a 'method'

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm trying to create a thread to reset the button colours in an application I'm writing, but whenever I try to create the Thread object, I get the error 'resetThread is a 'variable' but is used like a 'method'. This is the code I'm using to create the thread object:

```
System.Threading.Thread resetThread = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(resetThread));
```

And this is the code for the thread:

```
public void resetThread()
{
    while (true)
    {
        optionOne.BackColor = default(Color);
        optionTwo.BackColor = default(Color);
        optionThree.BackColor = default(Color);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

How do I go about fixing this? Thanks in advance. I have Googled to no avail.

Comment: You have both variable and method with name `resetThread`. Rename one of these.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call the thread something different to the method - call the method `reset()` for instance. You can't have a method and a field with the same name at class scope.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using the same name for your thread variable as for a method.

Just try to rename the variable name or the method name.

Answer (score 0):

Follow C# convention and rename your `resetThread` method to `ResetThread`, or precede `resetThread` with `this`:

```
Thread resetThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.resetThread));
```

Or both, for good practice.